# Snowflake SCIM - AzureAD groups to link with local groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a SCIM integration and provision groups and users from Azure AD to Snowflake. Is it possible to link these AAD groups with a local SF group?

I would like to link two groups to the local groups:

- AAD_AccountAdmin -> AccountAdminm
- AAD_SysAdmin -> SysAdmin

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **synchronizing** Azure AD groups to Snowflake, this is supported. You could configure the **Mappings** section with this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-provisioning-tutorial#step-5-configure-automatic-user-provisioning-to-snowflake).

For more information about Azure SCIM Integration with Snowflake, please refer to [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html).